# Storybook can't find main.js (React)

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I tried to install Storybook with React. Done it before and had no problems. However, this time I get an error telling "Error: No configuration files have been found in your configDir". So apparantly Storybook doesn't recognize its main.js. Everything is completely default: Used 'npx create-react-app' to create a new project and 'npx sb init' to add Storybook to the project. Didn't customize anything. The path to the project is D:\Starters\project so nothing crazy here either. I tried it multiple times, but keep getting the error. The old project I created earlier still runs without problems and it's also in the D:\Starters folder.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Probably it's this issue: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/17751

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out. The problem is that Storybook doesn't support React 18 yet. Create-react-app works with version 18 right now, so that's why it suddenly doesn't work anymore, while there were no problems in the past (when version 17 was used).

There are two solutions for this. I tried them both and they work.

1. Downgrade to version 17. You can do this by using create-react-app and change the version of react and react-dom to "^17.0.2" and @testing-library/react to "^12.1.2". Also you need to change index.jsx/.tsx to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

This is because 'react-dom/client' doesn't work with the older version of @testing-library/react, so you get an error elseways.

2. Use create-react-app with React18 en put a fix in a file in de Storybook node-module. You can find the instructions here: github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/17751 (thank you @tpliakas for the link)
   Unfortunately I couldn't get patch-package to work, so I need to change the file manually each time I create a new app, but if you manage to get it working, you can automate it.

hopefully this helps others who ran into the same problem.

Comment: Storybook already supports React 18. Simply run: `npx sb upgrade` to get storybook up to date. See: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/commit/815fc203b11ac8cb09dc4c38ba00443d7426ee94